# Need to sort a list using Wicket

Tags: list, sorting, wicket, comparable

I am working on a very simple program, looking like this:

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication implements Comparable<Object>{

private List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Mikkel", "20-02-91", 60169803),
        new Person("Jonas", "02-04-90", 86946512),
        new Person("Steffen", "15-07-90", 12684358),
        new Person("Rasmus", "08-12-93", 13842652),
        new Person("Michael", "10-10-65", 97642851));

/**
 * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#getHomePage()
 */
@Override
public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
    return SimpleView.class;
}

public static WicketApplication get() {
    return (WicketApplication) Application.get();
}

/**
 * @return @see org.apache.wicket.Application#init()
 */
public List<Person> getPersons() {
    return persons;
}

public List<Person> getSortedList(){
    return Collections.sort(persons);
    //This won't work before implementing comparator i know, but how??
}

@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();

    // add your configuration here
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

That was the class where i just put my people into a list.

```
public class SimpleView extends SimpleViewPage {


public SimpleView() {
    ListView persons = new ListView("persons", getPersons()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            Person person = (Person) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("name", person.getName()));
            item.add(new Label("birthdate", person.getBirthdate()));
            item.add(new Label("phone", person.getPhone()));
        }
    };
    add(persons);
    add(new Label("size", "Number of people " + getPersons().size()));
}
}
```

And here is what i do with the people. 
Basicly i want the program to show a table with all the data(this already works).
Now i want to be able to sort them. But i can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm still rather new at programming, and i want to have a button below my table that can sort on name, bday or phone number. Was thinking about trying to Comparable, but can't remember it that well, and not sure how it works with Wicket..

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the `DataView` component, which provides all the support you need for sorting (and paging, should you require it later on).

Here's a working [example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.SortingPage?2), if you click on the "Source Code" link in the top right corner, you can see that most of the things you want from a sortable table work out of the box. All you need is to create a suitable data provider.

If you use `DataView` with a [SortableDataProvider](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/util/SortableDataProvider.html), you don't need to worry about writing your own dynamic `Comparator`. (Which is not a terribly hard task itself, but it's easy to get it wrong.)

Comment: Is there any chance you could throw a bit of it into my code, just to get me started with it? Never really worked with Wicket untill my internship so having a hard time figuring this one out.

Comment: I think you'd be better off taking the source examples from the linked  address and playing around with them. That's how I learned a lot of techniques used in Wicket and I think it is the best way.

Comment: And I can thoroughly recommend the [Wicket in Action](https://wicket.apache.org/learn/books/wia.html) book too.

Comment: The thing is, when i take the example, which i have been sitting and trying to get to work for several hours, it just won't work. One example is this:

public class SortableContactDataProvider extends SortableDataProvider<Contact>

When i push this in, with Person instead of contact ofc, it wants to look like this:

public class SortablePersonDataProvider extends SortableDataProvider<Object, Object>.

I have no clue what to do really. Could use some help with the direct code :)

Comment: So, you just need set those generic params as <Person, String>. Second param - the type of the sorting parameter. 
May be this tutorial will help you better https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Simple+Sortable+DataTable+Example . 
Also, connect wicket source code to your project. It is very helpfull.